# Problems with Opening a Spreadsheet from Access, and Adding a VBAComponent

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to put together a function in Microsoft Access that will open a spreadsheet, add a VBComponent, save the spreadsheet, and close completely. The  code below seems to almost work, but doesn't save the changes when finished. Can someone tell me what I need to change in order to have the spreadsheet successfully save?

```
Sub AddSht_AddCode()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim xLine As Long


Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\U181873\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")

With wb
    Set xPro = .VBProject
    Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents("Sheet1")
    Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

    With xMod
        xLine = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
        xLine = xLine + 1
        .InsertLines xLine, "  Cells.Columns.AutoFit"
    End With
wb.Save
wb.Close
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: xslx is a non macro excel file, change to xlsm

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for calling that out! It's the little things that slip my mind sometimes.  I changed the format to xlsm and that seemed to do the trick, for anyone that is using this, if you add wb.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False just above wb.Save this will close the immediate window.